# Modify a captured image in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a plane which contain a `WebCamTexture` and a button to capture the image 
[image]

script to capture the image

```
void CaptureAndSave () {
    Debug.Log (Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture);
    Texture2D snap = new Texture2D(Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture.width, Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture.height);
    snap.SetPixels(Camera_panel_script.webCameraTexture.GetPixels());
    snap.Apply();
    Debug.Log (Application.persistentDataPath.ToString());
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(
        Application.persistentDataPath+"/my_image.png",
        snap.EncodeToPNG()
        );
}
```

[image]

this is the resulted image

how can i modify my code to add `the image` logo to my resulted picture ? so the captured image would look like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Unity Pro, one method would be to have a secondary Camera set in a way that only renders the captured image and the image above it into a RenderTexture, and then saving that RenderTexture. For RenderTextures you need to have Pro, however.

A way you could do this in Unity Free is copying each pixel from the image unsing GetPixel (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html) and putting each pixel in the correct position on your captured image with SetPixel (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html).

This is slow, however. You would need to cycle through every pixel on the image above and putting it in the correct position on the target image. And the, running Texture2D.Apply();

Comment: is there any live demo example that i can see ?

Comment: @Sora Hi, I don't have an example ready. What's the difficulty you're having? Have you tried changing individual pixels? Have you tried changing everypixel to a random color? These exercises could help you understand uses of the functions. If it is logic, think that you have to read pixels from the logo and putting then into the captured image, at a X and Y offset, and then doing Apply to the texture to see the changes. Hope it helps.